# purrr::map_df with nested data.frame

Tags: r, tidyr, purrr

I'd like to iterate over a series of dataframes and apply the same function to them all.

I'm trying this using `tidyr::nest` and `purrr::map_df`. Here's a reprex of the sort of thing I'm trying to achieve.

```
data(iris)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)

iris_df <- as.data.frame(iris)
my_var <- 2

my_fun <- function(df) {
  sum_df <- sum(df) + my_var
}

iris_df %>% group_by(Species) %>% nest() %>% map_df(.$data, my_fun)
# Error: Index 1 must have length 1
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there a different approach?

EDIT:
To clarify my desired output. Aiming for new column containing output eg

```
|Species|Data|my_function_output|
|:------|:---|:-----------------|
|setosa |<tibble>|509.1         |
```

Comment: could you give us an example of your desired output?

Comment: When you `nest()`, it actually creates a `list` column in your 'parent' data.frame (i.e., `iris`). To do what you want, you need to combine `mutate` with `map` like so: `%>% mutate(data = map(data, ~my_fun))`

Comment: @CPak ran `iris_df %>% group_by(Species) %>% nest() %>% mutate(my_col = map_df(data, ~my_fun))`. Returns `#Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : Evaluation error: Argument 1 must be a data frame or a named atomic vector, not a function.`

Comment: Apologies @CPak used `map_df` in error but `map` doesn't give correct output. `iris_df %>% group_by(Species) %>% nest() %>% mutate(my_col = map_dbl(data, my_fun))` as per @Renu gives output  needed.

Comment: @mark - You're right - I didn't look at the return value of your function - assumed it was a data.frame you were returning. `map_dbl` works as you've pointed out because you're returning a numeric value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `nest()` gives you a data.frame with a column `data` which is a list of data.frames. You need to `map` or `sapply` over the `data` column of the `nest()` output, not the entire `nest` output. I use `sapply`, but you could also use `map_dbl`. If you use `map` you will end up with `list` output, and `map_df` will not work because it requires named input.

```
iris_df %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(my_fun_out = sapply(data, my_fun))

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  Species    data              my_fun_out
  <fct>      <list>                 <dbl>
1 setosa     <tibble [50 x 4]>        509
2 versicolor <tibble [50 x 4]>        717
3 virginica  <tibble [50 x 4]>        859
```